# Finding first and last customer movement SQL Server - tips?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I needed some help with doing a task in a clever way. I want pick out the very first movement on customer number and sales day and the same thing but for their last movement.

Is there someway of doing this?

These are the column names:

- Cust_no
- type of sale
- sales day
- activation day
- campaign name
- seller name

I was thinking of first taking out their first movement with the help of

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cust_no ORDER BY sales day ASC)
```

separate these results in an Excel file

and last movement:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cust_no ORDER BY sales day DESC)
```

separate them in an Excel file.

Is there a way of attaching to an Excel file both first movement and last movement without doing it in parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select both rows using a subquery

```
SELECT *
FROM
( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cust_no ORDER BY sales day ASC) as seq1,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cust_no ORDER BY sales day DESC) as seq2,
) T
where T.seq1 =1 or T.seq2 =1
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input.This answer was though easier for me to implement. Thank you RADAR

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
SELECT *
FROM   tablename A
       JOIN (SELECT cust_no,
                    Min(sales_day) min_sal,
                    Max(sales_day) AS max_sal
             FROM   tablename) B
         ON a.cust_no = b.cust_no
            AND ( a.sales_day = b.min_sal
                   OR a.sales_day = b.max_sal )
```

Answer (score 1):

Get your first record as beginning then get the last one then do a Union between 2 results you can find a simple example in this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1485403/3836901).