# Get first AND last element with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In my Python (Flask) code, I need to get the first element and the last one sorted by a given variable from a SQLAlchemy query.

I first wrote the following code :

```
first_valuation = Valuation.query.filter_by(..).order_by(sqlalchemy.desc(Valuation.date)).first()
# Do some things
last_valuation = Valuation.query.filter_by(..).order_by(sqlalchemy.asc(Valuation.date)).first()
# Do other things
```

As these queries can be heavy for the PostgreSQL database, and as I am duplicating my code, I think it will be better to use only one request, but I don't know SQLAlchemy enough to do it...
(When queries are effectively triggered, for example ?)

What is the best solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) [How to get First and Last record from a sql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485391/how-to-get-first-and-last-record-from-a-sql-query) this is about how to get first and last records in one query.

2) [Here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html) are docs on sqlalchemy query. Specifically pay attention to `union_all` (to implement answers from above).
It also has info on when queries are triggered (basically, queries are triggered when you use methods, that returns results, like `first()` or `all()`. That means, `Valuation.query.filter_by(..).order_by(sqlalchemy.desc(Valuation.date))` will not emit query to database).

Also, if memory is not a problem, I'd say get `all()` objects from your first query and just get first and last result via python:

```
results = Valuation.query.filter_by(..).order_by(sqlalchemy.desc(Valuation.date)).all()
first_valuation = results[0]
last_valuation = results[-1]
```

It will be faster than performing two (even unified) queries, but will potentially eat a lot of memory, if your database is large enough.

Comment: Currently, one request means about ~15000 results, but I will use the second one until I get performance issues !

Comment: Yes, I'd go with two queries as it will decrease your DB load substantially. No need to pull all those 14998 objects from the DB when you want two.

Answer (score 1):

No need to complicate the process so much.

```
first_valuation = Valuation.query.filter_by(..).order_by(sqlalchemy.desc(Valuation.date)).first()
# Do some things
last_valuation = Valuation.query.filter_by(..).order_by(sqlalchemy.asc(Valuation.date)).first()
```

This is what you've and it's good enough. It's not heavy for any database. If you think that it's becoming too heavy, then you can always use some index.

Don't try to get all the results using `all()` and retrieving from it in `list` style. ***When you do, `all()` it loads everything into the memory which is extremely and extremely bad if you have a lot of results. It's a lot better to execute just two queries to get those items.***